# Are comparisons between iterator and const_iterator inefficient?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, iterator, constants

Variant a:

```
const auto end = whatever.end();
for (auto it = whatever.begin(); it != end; ++it)
{
    // ...
}
```

Variant b:

```
const auto end = whatever.cend(); // note the call to cend insteand of end here
for (auto it = whatever.begin(); it != end; ++it)
{
    // ...
}
```

Is there any reason to believe that variant b will be less efficient than variant a, since the loop condition compares two different kinds of iterators? Does this cause an implicit conversion on `it`?

(`end` is used multiple times inside the for loop, hence my desire to hoist it out.)

Comment: @David In my specific case, it's a `std::string`, but I'm curious in general.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In principle, it could be less efficient and result in an implicit conversion with non-zero cost.

In practice, `iterator` and `const_iterator` are likely to participate in an inheritance relationship (either one derives from the other, or both derive from an `_iterator_base`) such that the inequality operator is defined on the base class and there is no need for an implicit conversion (instead, the more-derived iterator gets ignored).  Even in the absence of these, the conversion is likely to be trivial enough to be inlined and optimised out.

libstdc++ optimises these comparisons differently, by defining `operator==` and `operator!=` between `iterator` and `const_iterator`: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a02037.html#l00295

libc++ doesn't have any optimisation: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/__tree - although again the constructor of `const_iterator` from `iterator` is so trivial that I'd expect it to be completely optimised out.